# How to call a templated method in a derived class that implements a pure virtual method in the base class?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have a base class with a couple of pure virtual methods, e.g.

```
class GenericFunction 
{
public:
  GenericFunction() { /* Init generic function state */ };
  virtual void Iterate(short *ps, unsigned cs) = 0;
  virtual void Iterate(float *ps, unsigned cs) = 0;
}
```

Then I have a bunch of derived classes that implement specific functions, and I want to call the `Iterate()` method on a collection of these functions, giving each of them a block of data samples. I only know the type of data at the moment that I'm calling `Iterate()`.

The `Iterate()` methods are almost exactly the same for many functions so I'd like to use a template. I can't use a template in the base class because virtual templates are not allowed. To get the compiler to generate the correct methods from the template, I found that I have to use an indirect call to the template like so:

```
class SpecificFunction : GenericFunction
{
public:
  SpecificFunction() : GenericFunction() { /* Init specific function state */ };

  template<class T> void IterateT(T *ps, unsigned cs) {
    // Do function operations on block of samples
  };
  virtual void Iterate(short *ps, unsigned cs) { IterateT(ps, cs); };
  virtual void Iterate(float *ps, unsigned cs) { IterateT(ps, cs); };
}
```

I don't want to make the entire class for `SpecificFunction` a template because there are many other methods, and all of that code is independent of the type of samples being operated on. I don't want all of that code replicated when it's generated from the template because it's going on an embedded processor and code space is limited.

This seems convoluted and inefficient. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: As a sidenote : don't forget to make the base destructor `virtual`.

Comment: You could template subclasses of SpecificFunction with just the templated code.

Comment: Do *all* child iterate functions call `IterateT`? Or do some have their own different implementation?

Comment: @John: But then wouldn't I have to make GenericFunction a template as well so that there is one `Iterate()` method to implement? It sounds promising, but how would it work, exactly?

Comment: @MarkB: Some children have different implementations that use inline assembly to speed them up. Those derived classes don't use a template and only have the two `Iterate()` methods for `short *` and `float *`.

Comment: Maybe the whole thing should be templated.  What are you really trying to do with this partial solution?

Comment: I'm trying to make sure duplicate code isn't being generated because code space is limited.

Comment: The code shown looks neither convoluted nor inefficient.

Comment: I agree with n.m.  There's a substantial amount of boilerplate code to connect the template instances and vtable slots, but it compiles away to *nothing*.  So the runtime efficiency (in terms of time and memory) should be quite good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case where the dreaded diamond (virtual inheritance and multiple inheritance) can help you. You can use a template proxy class that inherits virtually from your `GenericFunction` to be your common implementation. Then, use multiple inheritance on the specific implementations you want to create your `SpecificFunction`.

```
class ProxyState;

template <typename T>
class ProxyFunction : public virtual GenericFunction
{
public:
  ProxyFunction() : GenericFunction() {};
  virtual ProxyState * state () { return 0; }
  void Iterate (T *ps, unsigned cs) {
    // Do function operations on block of samples, using state()
    // if necessary
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
  }
};

class SpecificFunction : public ProxyFunction<short>,
                         public ProxyFunction<float>
{
public:
  SpecificFunction() : ProxyFunction<short>(),
                       ProxyFunction<float>()
  { /* Init specific function state */ };
};

//...
SpecificFunction s;
GenericFunction *g = &s;
g->Iterate((short *)0, 0);
g->Iterate((float *)0, 0);
```

The above program gives me the following output:

```
void ProxyFunction<T>::Iterate(T*, unsigned int) [with T = short int]
void ProxyFunction<T>::Iterate(T*, unsigned int) [with T = float]
```

Pictorially, the diagram looks like:

```
           GenericFunction
                 |
                /_\ (virtual)
                 |
           ProxyFunction<T>
                 |
     ____________|____________
     |                       |
ProxyFunction<short>    ProxyFunction<float>
     |                       |
    /_\                     /_\
     |_______         _______|
            |         |
          SpecificFunction
```

Because `GenericFunction` is inherited virtually, `SpecificFunction` only has one instance of it even though it is inheriting multiple `ProxyFunction<>`s.